# How to determine what coordinate is further North in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, mkannotationview, cllocation

I'm writing a custom annotation view for my latest iOS 5 app and I'm looking for the latest SDK friendly way to compare 2 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){33.0,-112.4};
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){33.0,-112.3};
```

Is there a built in method to determine something like this?

Comment: If the latitudes are equal, neither one is further north.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a built in method. You only have to compare the [latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){33.0,-112.4};
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){34.0,-112.3};

CLLocationCoordinate2D furthestNorth;
if (coordinate1.latitude > coordinate2.latitude) {
    furthestNorth = coordinate1;
} else {
    furthestNorth = coordinate2;
}
// OR
furthestNorth = (coordinate1.latitude > coordinate2.latitude) ? coordinate1 : coordinate2;
```

Comment: even better! wikipedia to the rescue!